# Is there any modern compiled language with manual memory management?

Tags: programming-languages

Is there any modern (generics, closures, object oriented) language with manual memory management? And with a compiler, either to machine code or to another language like c.

I haven't read of any. All new languages are garbage collected, and most of them interpreted or run in a vm.

*EDIT:* sorry, I know c++0x now has many new features, but I can't see it as a modern language. It's too ugly and illegible to me. And the way closures are used makes it worse.
By modern I meant something cleaner than c++.

Comment: Ugliness is a) completely subjective and b) not related to age or "modernness".

Comment: Sure, that's why I said "to me" :)

Comment: Objective-C, as used by Apple.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a C++0x version of C++ compiler (like the last gccs) then it does provide all the features you need. The C++03 (current version) does have generics, object orientation, have closures implementation (functors) but not the syntax (that is provided in C++0x, as "lambdas" - available in VS2010, gcc4.5 and other recent versions of compilers) and is all about manual (but easy) memory management (using RAII-the badly named idiom- and smart pointers where necessary).

Don't rely on c++ birth's date : what we call "modern C++" is clearly more easy and powerfull thant the original version of C++. (but it have a very long timing between new versions)

The only other alternative that I can think about is D, that is thought to be a system programming language too, that is similar to C++ in core principles but tries to avoid some of it's "problems" and provide some other features missing in C++.

Comment: "have closures implementation (functors)" How do functors close over anything? I'm also not sure that C++0x qualify as they do not affect the life-time of the closed over objects (which at least according to wikipedia is one of the defining characteristics of a closure).

Comment: @sepp2k: What he's really talking about is C++0x's lambdas. They do require you to specify the objects you want to capture (and how -- by reference or value), but do allow you to extend their lifetime to that of the lambda expression itself. As it happens, the lambda expression does produce an unnamed functor, but that part is only vaguely relevant.

Answer (score 1):

C++ (Don't laugh)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x

Rust - Not sure if its GC but it looks interesting
https://github.com/graydon/rust/wiki/Language-FAQ

Comment: rust has both garbage collection and manual memory management. [this blog post](http://pcwalton.github.io/blog/2013/03/18/an-overview-of-memory-management-in-rust/) that talks about it in more detail!

Answer (score 1):

Well, how modern is modern ?

Delphi requires that you manage your Memory, but provides simple and elegant ways to do that, it also has a pluggable architecture for memory management, and compiles to native code.

Delphi is still actively developed, nowadays by Embarcadero but was created originally in 1995 by Borland software, and even then was the successor to Turbo Pascal, so modern might be a subjective term for Delphi as its history is long.

Comment: Delphi ([1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(software)#History)) is more modern than Python ([1991](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Early_history) or [1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_1), depending what you view as the first release). I guess Python is considered a "modern" language, and therefore Delphi is more so!

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental language [BitC](http://www.bitc-lang.org/). It is quite low-level, compiles to a portable C, and have a lot of neat modern features.

A good old Ada also worth mentioning.